# Better solution to location.href

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have this following table:
[image: folder table]

This is basically loaded using `foreach` in `.cshtml` with `<tr><td>` append. When I click on a folder, it should get me the contents and reload the table with new contents. I use `.ajax` to get the contents, and use `window.location.href` to reload the page. However it takes really lot of time to reload the page using `location.href`. Also the performance of page is poor, since it again calls the server side code on `location.href`. What do you suggest for such a situation?

Comment: How do you handle client side cache ?

Comment: Why do you reload the page?

Comment: @Curt: How would I refresh the contents then on same table? The new contents are pulled from server.

Comment: @Heru-Luin: If you mean `.ajax` `cache`, then I have not mentioned anything specifically on ajax request, so by default it might be `true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said something about .cshtml so i will try to explain you how i do this in asp.net mvc.

You said you're using an ajax call. That's ok.

Please create a partial view (http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/617361/Partial-View-in-ASP-NET-MVC), which will be used to bring you the html for files view. And inside your action (which you call from ajax)

```
public JsonResult RenderFilesView(int renderMyFolderId){
  var folderModelWithFiles = this._repository.GetFolderAndFilesModel(renderMyFolderId);

  var filesViewHtml = this.RenderRazorViewToString("_FilesView", folderModelWithFiles);

  return Json(new { FilesViewHtml = filesViewHtml });
}
```

RenderPartialViewToString here: [Render partial view to string MVC4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19142597/render-partial-view-to-string-mvc4)

And you will receive in your success function of ajax call the FilesViewHtml.

```
$.ajax( url: 'godKnows/RenderFilesView', 
        success: function(response){

               // access response.FilesViewHtml 
               // And you can do something like: 
               $('#container').html(response.FilesViewHtml);
        });
```

And no need to reload the page or god knows what.

Comment: I knew this approach, but somehow I have been avoiding it because of generating ugly strings of HTMLs in c# . However, it seems like that's the only way to do this requirement... anyways thanks for your answer :)